# Android - stretched EditText above Button

Tags: android

I want to put a scrollable EditText above a row of buttons such that the text component fills all the vertical space left free by the buttons. This is proving surprisingly difficult, not least because the ADT is buggy: it suggests that this layout will do and it does in Eclipse but not in the real application!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view1"/>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/view1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <!-- buttons go here -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this layout the text stretches to the full screen, as you might expect, i.e., it goes under the button but the ADT graphical layout tool shows it stopping just above the button. OTOH if you give it a wrap_content height then of course it doesn't stretch. layout_weight is of no help either.

So, is there a way? You **must** test your answer in the emulator or on a real device, not merely in Eclipse.

---

Precision: what makes me think this is not working and that the text widget extends under the buttons is the shape of the scrollbar at the bottom (see pic. below): it should be rounded at both ends and instead it looks like the bottom extends farther. If you compares its shape at the bottom with the shape it has at the top (which unfortunately I was unable to capture: it disappears too fast) it is very clearly different. OTOH the text widget boundary looks as expected. This is very confusing. Maybe just a minor bug in Android?

[image]

Comment: `android:layout_above="@+d/view1"/>` isn't it supposed to be `android:layout_above="@+id/view1"/>`

Comment: Why don't you try LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout? I think,that would solve your problem.

Comment: @PH7, yes that was a typo; I just fixed it.

Comment: @Hiral No, with linear you lose the option of specifying that the text widget must stop at the buttons and match_parent causes it to really take the whole screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: @olefevre. Please accept answer if this is answer suitable for you

Comment: Unfortunately that's no answer because the text widget does not stretch vertically!

Comment: I think he wants the EditText to only be as wide as the buttons? If so, the top LinearLayout's layout_width should be wrap_content

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I don't think my original description was confusing. This is clearly about vertical, not horizontal stretching.

Comment: @olefevre, I just made some changes. Please look it!

Comment: @ihrupin Weird. I'm sure I had tried the layout_weight=1 trick at some point. Anyway, this works fine: the scrollbar looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">   
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/view1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"/>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@id/view1"
        android:gravity="top"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since fill_parent is the same as match_parent that is the same layout I had already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing with TextView and a Button at the bottom.I tried to put EditText in place of TextView there and it works fine for me. You can try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">   

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Add New Template"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"     
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/add_acronym"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the snapshot-

[image]

Comment: My comment to blessenm below applies.